# How can I replace a word while keeping the original casing?

Tags: replace, letter-case

Basically:

```
cat -> horse
CAT -> HORSE
Cat -> Horse
```

I know this is underspecified (e.g. unclear what cAt should become). However, is there a canonical solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plug-in implements a `:Subvert` command that performs substitutions taking case in consideration. (It can also preserve plurals, including exceptions in plural forms.)

See [the README file](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish/blob/master/README.markdown#substitution) with examples, specifically on case:

> Oh, but the case variants!
>
> ```
> :%s/Facility/Building/g
> :%s/FACILITY/BUILDING/g
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Abolish.vim has your back. One command to do all six, and you can repeat it with `&` too!
>
> ```
> :%Subvert/facilit{y,ies}/building{,s}/g
> ```